# Is there a way to echo a list of all Drives/Partitions e.g C:\ D:\ E:\ etc and prompt the user to choose one of them to do some function?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am wondering if there's a way to check and echo the list of all available drives/partitions  on the PC and prompt the user to choose one of them by typing its letter and hitting enter to submit. Then the batch file will proceed.

The desirable outcome may be like?

```
@echo off
echo List all drives partitions... Hit enter to continue
C, D, E, F
echo Choose a drive to proceed
```

Here the user will type the preferred Drive letter

```
D
echo proceeding on D:\
```

Thanks to the responders

Comment: To get help with your code, please show your code.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. (You' need the following commands: `wmic`, `for /f`, `set` and `choice`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "list= "
for /f "skip=1 delims=:" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') do (
  set "list=!list!%%a"
)
choice /c %list% /m "Enter drive "
set "disk=!list:~%errorlevel%,1!:"
echo you chose %disk%
```

If you want to limit to hard disks only, use

```
... in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" get caption') do ...
```

Comment: `… where DriveType^=3 …` or `… where "DriveType=3" …`…

Comment: @aschipfl Ah, that's why the question yesterday looked so familiar. Corrected (Thank you)

Answer (score 0):

`MountVol` may be sufficient for your needs:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "i=0"&For /F "Delims==" %%# In ('Set # 2^>NUL')Do @Set "%%#="
For /F %%# In ('MountVol^|Find ":\"')Do (Set /A i+=1
    Set "#!i!=%%~d#"&Echo !i!. %%~d#)
:Ask
Echo(&Set /P "Drive=Choose a drive to proceed>"
Set #|Findstr "^#%Drive%=">Nul||GoTo :Ask
Set "Drive=!#%Drive%!"

Echo(Proceeding on %Drive%&Timeout 3 >NUL

EndLocal
GoTo :EOF
```